# Two versions of ABAP documentation

Tags: abap

What is the difference between the following SAP ABAP help documents.

Why are their two set of documents for the same product - ABAP

http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/
and
http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/43/41341147041806e10000000a1553f6/frameset.htm

Why would SAP want to maintain 2 seperate set of documentation for ABAP?

Answer (score 5):

Because 7.02 and 7.31 are actually different versions, believe it or not. There are a number of articles on SCN that go into the details, like [this one](http://scn.sap.com/community/it-management/alm/software-logistics/blog/2012/12/21/why-ehp6-for-sap-erp-60-contains-sap-basis-731).